# perceptron algorithm calculation of local error / RMSE

Tags: java, machine-learning, perceptron

I have a strong suspicion it has something to do with the local error, which seems always to be `-1`.

The full code can be found on my [**github page**](https://github.com/h1395010/perceptron).

I've implemented the perceptron algorithm in accordance with [**this tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aksMtJHWEQ).

My input is a bag of words feature vector, of the form:

Example:

```
Document 1 = ["I", "am", "awesome"]
Document 2 = ["I", "am", "great", "great"]
```

Dictionary is:

```
["I", "am", "awesome", "great"]
```

So the documents as a vector would look like:

```
Document 1 = [1, 1, 1, 0]
Document 2 = [1, 1, 0, 2]
```

However, when I run the algorithm I consistently get either `0.0`, `1.0`, or `0.7071067811865476` as the value for the root mean squared error, i.e. `Math.sqrt(globalError / inputSize)`.

This cannot possibly be correct sine I initialize the weights to different random varaibles every time. Also I think the number of iterations is rather low, as I have hundreds of words as my global dictionary.

I've been looking online and carefully picked through the code with the debugger and I think I've implemented the algorithm correctly, but there must be something I'm not catching, maybe one of you can spot it.

This is the output result of three different executions:

First:

```
Iteration 1 : RMSE = 1.0
Iteration 2 : RMSE = 1.0
Iteration 3 : RMSE = 1.0
Iteration 4 : RMSE = 1.0
Iteration 5 : RMSE = 0.7071067811865476
Iteration 6 : RMSE = 0.0

=======
Decision boundary equation:
 bias: 4.9148000000000005
class = 1
```

Second:

```
Iteration 1 : RMSE = 0.7071067811865476
Iteration 2 : RMSE = 1.0
Iteration 3 : RMSE = 0.7071067811865476
Iteration 4 : RMSE = 1.0
Iteration 5 : RMSE = 1.0
Iteration 6 : RMSE = 1.0
Iteration 7 : RMSE = 1.0
Iteration 8 : RMSE = 0.7071067811865476
Iteration 9 : RMSE = 0.0

=======
Decision boundary equation:
 bias: -4.8511
class = 1
```

Third:

```
Iteration 1 : RMSE = 1.0
Iteration 2 : RMSE = 1.0
Iteration 3 : RMSE = 1.0
Iteration 4 : RMSE = 1.0
Iteration 5 : RMSE = 0.7071067811865476
Iteration 6 : RMSE = 0.0

=======
Decision boundary equation:
 bias: 9.7544
class = 1
```

The code looks like this:

```
public static void perceptron(Set<String> globoDict,
    Map<String, int[]> trainingPerceptronInput,
    Map<String, int[]> testPerceptronInput)
{
    final int globoDictSize = globoDict.size(); // number of features (x, y, z)

    // weights total 32 (31 for input variables and one for bias)
    double[] weights = new double[globoDictSize + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) 
    {
        //weights[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) / 10000;
        weights[i] = randomNumber(-10 , 10);
    }

    int inputSize = trainingPerceptronInput.size();
    int[] outputs = new int[inputSize];
    final double[][] a = initializeOutput(trainingPerceptronInput, globoDictSize, outputs);

    double globalError;
    int iteration = 0;
    do 
    {
        iteration++;
        globalError = 0;
        // loop through all instances (complete one epoch)
        for (int p = 0; p < inputSize; p++) 
        {
            // calculate predicted class
            int output = Prcptrn_CalcOutpt.calculateOutput(THETA, weights, a, p);
            // difference between predicted and actual class values
            double localError = outputs[p] - output;
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
            {
                weights[i] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * a[i][p];
            }
            weights[i] += LEARNING_RATE * localError;

            // summation of squared error (error value for all instances)
            globalError += localError * localError;
        }

        /* Root Mean Squared Error */
        System.out.println("Iteration "
            + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt(globalError / inputSize));
    } 
    while (globalError != 0 && iteration <= MAX_ITER);

    System.out.println("\n=======\nDecision boundary equation:");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.print(" a");
        if (i < 10) System.out.print(0);
        System.out.println( i + " * " + weights[i]);


    }
    System.out.println(" bias: " + weights[i]);

    inputSize = testPerceptronInput.size();
    outputs = new int[inputSize];
    double[][] z = initializeOutput(testPerceptronInput, globoDictSize, outputs); 

    test_output = Prcptrn_CalcOutpt.calculateOutput(THETA, weights, z, 1);       

    System.out.println("class = " + test_output);
}

static double[][] initializeOutput( Map<String, int[]> perceptronInput, 
                                    int size, 
                                    int[] outputs)
{
    final int inputSize = perceptronInput.size();
    final double[][] a = new double[size][inputSize];

    // 2d array for features
    int[][] feature_matrix = new int[inputSize][size];
    String[] output_label = new String[inputSize];
    int x = 0;
    for (Entry<String, int[]> entry : perceptronInput.entrySet()) 
    {
        int[] container = entry.getValue();

        for (int j = 0; j < container.length; j++) 
        {
            feature_matrix[x][j] = container[j];
            output_label[x] = String.valueOf(entry.getKey());
        }
        x++;
    }

    for (x = 0; x < inputSize; x++) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
        {
            a[i][x] = feature_matrix[x][i];
        }
        outputs[x] = output_label[x].equals(FILEPATH) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    return a;
}

public static double randomNumber(int min , int max) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
    double d = min + Math.random() * (max - min);
    String s = df.format(d);
    double x = Double.parseDouble(s);
    return x;
}
```

This is `Prcptrn_CalcOutpt.calculateOutput`:

```
static int calculateOutput(int theta, double[] weights, double[][] a, int index)
{
    double sum = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        sum += weights[i] * a[i][index];
    }
    sum += weights[i];
    return (sum >= theta) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean hard limit activation function?

Comment: It's hard to guess what your code does from just looking at it. Can you post a complete, self-contained example which reproduces the described behaviour (including some test data)?

Comment: yeah sure, one sec, I'll put it to my github. 

I changed them to double, still the same.

Comment: https://github.com/h1395010/perceptron @Matt voila! you'll need to modify the path to the data files though, I tried to do it myself but it was taking too long, please forgive me

Comment: that's all located in 'Main.java'

Comment: it seems that my local error is alway equal to -1, maybe that's the issue

Comment: Unfortunately I can't debug your code from here.My guess is, that there is somewhere a loss of precision (probably when multiplying `int` with `double` or a similar mistake). Make sure to check the error propagation and your gradients by debugging your code. Also this line `(sum >= theta) ? 1 : 0;` looks fishy to me. What kind of activation function are you supposed to use?

Comment: what do you mean by 'looks fishy', looks to be wrong? looks to be misplaced?

Comment: @Matt the code was changed in accordance with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585880/manually-enumerated-data-structs-need-loops-to-generalize-perceptron-algorithm) do you think that the suggested refactorization there is accurate?

Comment: @Matt I don't know if it's fishy, I see the same type of thing [here](https://github.com/jakl/hacks/blob/master/perceptron/perceptron.java) on line 91

Comment: He stated that the code is untested. What's missing for me is some kind of activation function (sigmoid, rectified linear etc.). Maybe you can check your code against this and see if you can spot the error yourself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169280/implementing-a-perceptron-with-backpropagation-algorithm But I guess you'll eventually have to debug your code yourself. Good luck.

Comment: I think you're messing up the indexes: `sum += weights[i] * a[i][index];` it probably should be `a[index][i]`

Comment: @Matt he is using a step function for activation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)

Comment: @ThomasJungblut hey herr thomas! I just tried that but it crashed with an index out of bounds

Comment: maybe instead of using 0 and 1, I should -1 and 1?

Comment: Yeah, because you need to loop until `a[i].length`

Comment: whoaaa, i think you're exactly-fokken-right!

Comment: god damn herr thomas you're clever as hell, clever as mephistopheles

Comment: but is it strange that the RMSE is still only either 1.0, 0.0 or that long 0.7... ?